# Href working on one page but not on another?

Tags: php, html, jquery-cycle2

This href I have on a page is included in a cycle 2 slider so a caption under an image. BUT it doesn't work when clicking and it opening a new tab, it only works when you right click and then click "go to ....". Does anyone know why?

The plugin on wordpress: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Code: 
`<a class="alt-caption" href="http://<?php the_field('url_site'); ?>"><?php the_field('url_site'); ?></a>`

```
      <div class="paginawrap no_overflow">
        <div class="wraptest">
          <div class="cycle-slideshow" 
               data-cycle-fx="carousel" 
               data-cycle-speed="500" 
               data-cycle-delay=5000
               data-cycle-next=" > img"
               data-cycle-caption=".alt-caption"
               data-cycle-caption-template="{{alt}}"
               data-cycle-carousel-fluid=true
               data-allow-wrap=false
          >
<?php $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'project',
        'posts_per_page' => 10
      );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $query->have_posts()) :
        while ( $query->have_posts()) :  $query->the_post();
          the_post_thumbnail('home');
        endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
        endif; ?>

         <a href=" http://<?php the_field('url_site'); ?> "> <div class="alt-caption"></div></a>
          </div>
          <div class="archief1">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: When you inspect your website with the Chrome Developer Toolbar, for instance, you can see that the image slider removes the value for the href attribute -> your link is empty, as soon as a slide is executed

Comment: How would I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your href is empty. Let's have a look at your source code:

```
<a class="alt-caption external" href="http://">www.aimassociates.nl</a>
```

The href attribute is looking at "http://".

Maybe you must add an echo?

```
<?php echo the_field('url_site'); ?>
```

It's weird that the same PHP code returns different result, have you copy/paste the code just as is in your files?

Why don't you try this?

```
<?php $site_url = the_field('url_site'); ?>
<a class="alt-caption" href="http://<?php echo $site_url; ?>"><?php echo $site_url; ?></a>
```

Comment: Yea I have it's so strange I did the same exact thing on a different page. Although there it's not moving so i'm suspecting that cycle 2 is emptying it. Unfortunately echo didn't do the trick.

Comment: Can you post your the_field() php function in order to see what's going on?

Comment: your code gives the url null on the href section <a class="alt-caption" href="">www.rrkc.nl</a>

the_field('url_site'); must have to return something. please check that

Comment: It has no function it's a field created with a plugin called "Advanced custom fields" and all you need to do is call to the_field('your selected field'); and that would be it as well as it worked on another page..

Comment: @VineeshKalarickal that's because I tried Mr.FF's way of linking but i'll return in now

Comment: Have a look at my edited post, you can try to get the URL before and use the stored in the var

Comment: I also noticed that however I alter the href it'll always leave href empty and just end the sentence like so: `<a class="alt-caption" href=""> ` It'll even ignore http://

Comment: I tried it before and it as well results in this: `<a class="alt-caption external" href="http://">www.rrkc.nl</a>` Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with href but it denies all php code for some reason.. But since cycle 2 has nothing to do with hrefs whatsoever I don't understand what exactly overrides the "href" to a point it empties it..

Comment: Must be javascript, but i don't understand the reason to do that. As you cannot use the "href" i'm figuring out that you can use the onclick function to do this with javascript. Do you know basic JS?

Comment: Yep good idea I guess i'll do onclick it was sort of my last resort anyway. Yes I do luckily so I suppose i'll do that, thanks for all the effort mate! I'll give you the answer then.

Comment: Ok! If you need help with the JS, let me know, hope it works!

Comment: I found out about something, the same string of code isn't working on the entire page at all as if that piece of php code gets entirely denied. Though there are multiple pieces of php on the page for example the standard `the_content();` So there must be a mistake somewhere? (I think I must solve this in case it'll give me problems I can't bypass later)

Comment: Try to get the field???

$field_name = "text_field";

$field = get_field_object($field_name);
 
echo $field['label'] . ': ' . $field['value'];

Comment: Look at this page:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-i-add-the-get-field-in-plugin

It's your exact problem and seems solved

Comment: I completely figured it out I think, the field needs to be filled in in the cms which of course isn't appointed to this page but to a project which I completely overlooked. I'm so sorry for all the trouble i'm so stupid. Got it by getting the values yea thannks!

Comment: I do have a question, is it possible to use`class= "alt-caption"` as `href="here"` somehow?

Comment: I don't think so, because you want elements with the same class pointing to different links, isn't it?

Comment: I GOT IT OMG! It of course didn't get the stuff because it wasn't in the while above now the problem is that it shows 3x(as many times as there are pictures in the slider) I just have to solve that! I didn't realise at all till now because I had `'post_type' => 'project',` and I was like why doesn't it work if the `the_field('url_site');` echo works on that other page and then it hit me. xD

Answer (score 0):

You use php to load the link. Why not use php the entire way for that line of code? Something like this:

```
echo('<a class="alt-caption" href="' . $the_field . '" target="_blank"><' . $the_field . '></a>');
```

Also make sure that your homepage correctly reads the php data.

Comment: Unfortunately this re-links it back to the same page it is on.. But I get your logic and it should've worked..

Comment: <a class="alt-caption" href="">www.luchtsingel.org</a> Is what happens and I altered your code a bit. `<?php $the_field = the_field('url_site'); echo('<a class="alt-caption" href="' . $the_field . '">' . $the_field . '"</a>'); ?>`

Comment: Strange, do you get the same behavior on the first picture link as well? Edited my post and added target=_blank so it opens in a new window.

Comment: It automatically opens a new window and yes even on the first so it immediately empties it..I thought it should've worked on the first one regardless before even swapping pics once but appearently it's not so. And again with every method what it does is it just opens the same page on a new tab.. `<a class="alt-caption" href="" target="_blank">www.rrkc.nl</a>`

Comment: Could you try this and tell me the result, change `<?php $the_field = the_field('url_site');` to `<?php $the_field = "http://www.google.com";`

Comment: To be exact it doesn't just link me to google.com but `https://www.google.nl/?gws_rd=cr&ei=OYrnUvHoEurI0wWBvIDYAw` I don't know why cycle 2 adds that but that's the place I get to.

Comment: As well as : `<a class="alt-caption external" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">www.aimassociates.nl</a>`

Comment: Strange behavior, it seems that whatever code you use for cycling the pictures is having a life of its own! Is it possible for you to post that code?

Comment: Of course but there is one thing I want to mention, whereever I paste the piece of code it's not working..but on other pages it does work. I'll edit my post then. So that means the entire page is bugged? Although there is more php on the page itself then that only which is properly working as well as above or under this code.

Comment: You will need to add the code or the link to the plug-in that handles the url_site function.

Comment: Another note, normal php seems to work like `the_title();` I put it in href and it returns me: `<a href="Home">` which upon click returns me to the same page but that's quite obvious. Which means that `the_field('url_site')` won't work at all.